# Using bind for form with lot of inputs (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bind

I have form with lot of inputs, and I'm trying to import them in database (mysql).
I want to use bind but trying to avoid writing all variables so many times. Probably I can't explain so good, so I will here is a code

```
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){

    $firstName=trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName=trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $gender=trim($_POST['gender']);

    if(!empty($firstName)&& !empty($lastName)) {
        $unos = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (firstName,lastName,gender) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $unos->bind_param('sss', $firstName, $lastName, $gender);

        if($unos->execute()) {....
```

1.Well this is working fine , and it's not a problem, but now I want to add more inputs so I tried this

```
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){

    $firstName=trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName=trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $gender=trim($_POST['gender']);

    $param=array('$firstName','$lastName','$gender');
    $type='sss';
    $param_list = implode(',', $param);

    if(!empty($param)) {
        $unos = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (firstName,lastName,gender) VALUES (?,?,?)"); 
        $unos->bind_param($type,implode(',', $param));

        if($unos->execute()) {....
```

and it's not working. I get "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables"...
I don't get it, because when I echo this implode thing I get what I need. 
I'm pretty newbie with PHP, so help will be so precious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){

    $firstName=trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName=trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $gender=trim($_POST['gender']);

    $param=array('firstName' => 's','lastName' => 's','gender' => 's');

    if(!empty($param)) {
      $unos = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (". implode(',', array_keys($param) .") VALUES (". implode(',', array_fill(0, count($param), '?')) .")"); 
      foreach($param as $paramName => $paramType) {
          $unos->bind_param($paramType, $paramName);
      }


      if($unos->execute()) {....
```

You can pus as many parameters to `$param` array. Key should the name of the db column, value is its type.

Comment: Great idea @gellu, Thanks! But now i'm getting "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\homework\db\unos.php on line 14", the line with SQL query. Something with array_fill i guess. any thought?

Comment: Yeah, there was `implode` missing. Edited, it should work fine now.

Comment: :/ , now I get "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement " ,on line with bind->param() , the same thing I got with my code..

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable for each question mark, but you will also need to bind each of the parameters separately. In your current situation, you bind a comma-separated list of values as a single string parameter.

What about this? I attempted to make the entire code rely on a single array of fields. If you want extra fields, you can just add them to the array and the rest of the code should respond to it. I don't have a proper test environment at hand and I typed this code by heart, so sorry for any typos. :)

```
// The fixes list of allowed/expected fields. Other values are ignored.
$fields = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'gender');

// Check if each value exists, and put them in an array.
$paramvalues = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) do
{
  if (!isset($_POST[$field])) 
    die("missing field $field");

  $paramvalues[] = & $_POST[$field]; // Bind_param wants a ref value, hence `&`
}

// Build a list of fields for the dynamic query.
$fieldlist = implode($fields, ',');
// And a list of placeholders.
$paramlist = implode(array_fill(0, count($fields), '?'), ',');
// And a list of types, assuming all parameters are strings.
$paramtypes = str_pad('', count($fields), 's');

// Prepare the query
$unos = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members ($fieldlist) VALUES ($paramlist)"); 

// Build an array of reference values to be passed to call_user_func_array:
$paramrefvalues = array();
$paramrefvalues[] = $paramtypes
foreach ($paramvalues as $value) do
{
  $paramrefvalues[] = & $value;
}

// Call bind_param using this array of by-ref parameters
call_user_func_array(array($unos, 'bind_param'), $paramrefvalues);
```

This code is loosely based on [this article](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)

Comment: Thanks for answer @GolezTrol! I tried this way and I got "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object", can u help about that? And after`code`( paramrefvalues = array();
$paramrefvalues[] = $paramtypes
foreach ($paramvalues as $value)
{
  $paramredvalues = & $value;
})`code`

Comment: I think the `&` needs to be removed on the last line, but maybe the prepare failed as well. Can you check the value of `$unos` (whether it is an object or `false`)? I also made a typo in the loop that filled `$paramrefvalues`, but that is also fixed now in the answer.

Comment: Ye ,that typo I corrected in my code, but when I write $paramrefvalues = array();
  $paramrefvalues[] = $paramtypes;
  foreach ($paramvalues as $value) 
  {
   $paramredvalues[] = & $value;
  }
  var_dump($paramrefvalues); die(); , var_dump gives me back only string 'sss' (that is $paramtypes) and there is no any value from $paramvalues

Comment: and var_dump($unos); give back bool(false)

Comment: In that code you just commented it still says `paramredvalues` (red instead of ref). Also if $unos is false, that means that prepare has failed. Maybe `$db` is not connected, or there is an error in the query after all. Can you `var_dump("INSERT INTO members ($fieldlist) VALUES ($paramlist)");` before prepare to see if the query looks allright? And check whether the database connection ($db) is correctly setup?